# How can I obtain the colnames from part of a sorted matrix column?

Tags: r

I have the following in R:

```
> require("pls")
> set.seed(42)
> a = matrix(rnorm(12), ncol=4)
> a
           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]
[1,]  1.3709584  0.6328626  1.51152200 -0.0627141
[2,] -0.5646982  0.4042683 -0.09465904  1.3048697
[3,]  0.3631284 -0.1061245  2.01842371  2.2866454

> b <- c(1, 2, 3)
> mymodel <- pcr(b ~ a)
> mymodel$loadings

Loadings:
   Comp 1 Comp 2
a1  0.654  0.165
a2  0.136 -0.255
a3  0.415  0.732
a4 -0.618  0.609

> comp1 <- mymodel$loadings[, 1]
> comp1
        a1         a2         a3         a4
 0.6539036  0.1362937  0.4146222 -0.6179988
> sort(comp1, decreasing=TRUE)
        a1         a3         a2         a4
 0.6539036  0.4146222  0.1362937 -0.6179988
> sort(comp1, decreasing=TRUE)[1]
       a1
0.6539036
```

I am really puzzled by what comp1 is:

```
> colnames(comp1)
NULL
> rownames(comp1)
NULL
> dim(comp1)
NULL
> str(comp1)
 Named num [1:4] 0.654 0.136 0.415 -0.618
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "a1" "a2" "a3" "a4"
> typeof(comp1)
[1] "double"
```

Questions:

1. What data structure is comp1?
2. What should I do to obtain the column names from the sorted comp1 to get `"a1", "a3", "a2", "a4"`?

Comment: It is a named numeric vector. Use `names`.

Comment: `class(comp1); is.vector(comp1); names(comp1)`

Comment: I understand it is a rather silly question but why all the down-votes? It shows some effort, provides all the required code, and there is a well defined question.

Comment: Some SO responders get a bit carried away with the down votes - I thought your question was very clearly stated and one that I know other users have encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good question in lots of ways, since these small but very important distinctions vex many new and even intermediate R users.  In this case your call to `pcr` returned a list called `mymodel`.  Your question showed you use the `str()` method to examine return objects, and this is always the best place to start.  You can also consult the help page `?pcr` which explains that the return is a list of named components plus "all components returned by the underlying fit function".  For `pcr()`, the underlying fit function is `svdpc.fit`, and the help page for that function details the remaining items in the `my model` list.

As you can see from below, `mymodel$loadings` is a numeric vector with two named dimensions (through the list `dimnames`), also known as a matrix.  Your use of the `[` operator to slice out the first column (in my code, named by "Comp 1" since this is both more clear and less likely to break should the column order ever change) returns a simple numeric vector because you have chosen only a single column from the matrix.  You can tell this is not a matrix because it has no dimensions, only a length.

```
> str(mymodel$loadings)
 loadings [1:4, 1:2] 0.654 0.136 0.415 -0.618 0.165 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "a1" "a2" "a3" "a4"
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "Comp 1" "Comp 2"
> is.matrix(mymodel$loadings)
[1] TRUE

> str(mymodel$loadings[, "Comp 1"])
 Named num [1:4] 0.654 0.136 0.415 -0.618
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "a1" "a2" "a3" "a4"

> dim(mymodel$loadings[, "Comp 1"])
NULL
```

The way that R drops dimensions when you extract only a single-column slice is not always the behaviour you would prefer, especially if you want to write general code that returns the same object type.  One way around this, where `colnames()` *would* work for you, is to use the `drop = FALSE` argument in `[`.  (See `?"["`)  This keeps the matrix with its dimensions and dimnames:

```
> altslice <- mymodel$loadings[, "Comp 1", drop = FALSE]
> colnames(altslice)
[1] "Comp 1"
> dim(altslice)
[1] 4 1
> is.matrix(altslice)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @Roland and @Legalizeit's comment,

the answer is to use `names`